# Unusual problem with multiple return in Python

Tags: python

When I call the function "`G()`" which returns two values: `p_T` and `q_T` twice (see below) but using the same style, that's, `P_T, neg = G(); U, Ign = G()` and print sums of `P_T` and `U`, I get two different answers! Another thing is that both answers are incorrect!

I have only included part of the code which can simply aid in explaining the idea. The block of statements within the function `G()` under the for loop is executed N times as the loop suggests. Is there something being compromised by global variables declaration?

Any suggestion of what is wrong and how to fix it is appreciated!

```
def G():
    global p_T; global q_T

    for n in range(N):
        p_T = U_T(EvolveU_T(p_T))
        q_T = V_T(EvolveV_T(q_T))

    return p_T, q_T

P_T, neg = G()
print sum(P_T)
U, Ign = G()
print sum(U)
```

Comment: @Liutauras there is no reason to double space the code.

Comment: there is no way for us to help without knowing what `?_T` and `Evolve?_T` are. Also, please rewrite your title, "Multiple return" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: in general, don't use so many global variables.  why?  because you end up with strange bugs like this...

Answer (score 4):

You have global state. You mutate global state. Then you mutate it again, starting where you left off. So P_T is a result after N operations, and U is a result after 2N operations.

Don't use global state.

Answer (score 2):

Because `p_T` and `q_T` are globals, their scope is not local to the function. So it's no surprise that you get two different answers after calling the function twice. Here's a simple example that demonstrates what's going on:

```
class C:
    foo = ''

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.foo

x, y = C(), C()

def F():
    global x
    global y

    x.foo += 'x'
    y.foo += 'y'

    return (x, y)

print F()
print F()
```

The globals x and y maintain their values because they are not scoped to the function. If they were declared and initialized inside the function without the `global` modifiers, you'd see (x, y) twice. But instead you see:

```
(x, y)
(xx, yy)
```

Generally globals are considered bad programming practice as they can lead to a confusing amount of state which is not localized to the function under consideration, as you've discovered.